# How to use a range function in a normal command?

Tags: vimscript

```
:set cc=1,5,9,13,17
```

The command above here can create a series red lines on the edited file in vim whose version is lager than 7.3.

Why can't write it as `:set cc=range(1,17,4)`  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two reasons you can't use this syntax:

- Firstly you can't mix functions calls and normal commands without distinction. Your syntax should be `exec ":set cc=" . range(1, 17, 4)`. to concatenate the result of the function `range()` with the normal command `:set cc=`.
- Secondly even with this syntax your command will not work: When you use `:echo range(1, 17, 4)` you get a list: `[1, 5, 9, 13, 17]` so the previous command would expand to `:set cc=[1, 5, 9, 13, 17]` which isn't a correct syntax.

A possible solution would be to cast the result of `range` as a string, remove the `[` and `]` characters and then concatenate the result with `:set cc=` with the `exec` command.

**Edit** @Saginaw suggested to use the function `join()` to implement the transformation of the list to a string without brackets characters. Using this idea the final solution for your question would be:

Use this:

```
exec "set cc=" . join(range(1, 17, 4), ",")
```

Thanks to @Saginaw for his idea.

---

You might want to read:

- [`:h :execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute)
- [`:h join()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#join())

Comment: You could use the `join()` function with the second argument `','` which would give: `execute 'set colorcolumn=' . join(range(1, 17, 4), ',')`. You could also use the following syntax: `let &l:colorcolumn = join(range(1, 17, 4), ',')` The prefix `&l:` is used to change the window-local value of the option (instead of the global one).

Comment: @saginaw: Your use of `join()` is indeed the good way to go, do you mind if I add it to my answer? About the `let &l:colorcolumn` I guess it depends on what OP wants to do :-)

Comment: Ah yes you're right, the window-local scope was maybe not a good idea. Yes, if you think `join()` is a good idea, you should add it to the answer. If the window-local scope is not what the OP wants, in the 2nd syntax you could simply remove `l:`.

Comment: Thanks I'll add it with credits to your name. For the local scope I don't see a situation where the user you'll need 4 colored strips on all of his windows so your idea seems wise but as OP didn't specify that we can only guess.

Comment: Using `let &cc = join('1, 17, 4), ',')` as @saginaw suggested is shorter and accomplishes the same result :)

Comment: Damn indeed that is shorter, I focused on the `&l` part and didn't even realize that the important point of @saginaw's solution was that he used a more clever solution. As the approach is pretty different (and better!) than mine I guess that would be worth a second answer :-)